# Convert ABI to HTML interface (input)

Tags: solidity, dapps, abi, interfaces

Is there a way to get code that convert ABI to HTML interface ? I found example in multiples apps but can't find the code, lot of dead github.

Apps where I find what I want :

https://abi.hashex.org/

https://oneclickdapp.com/

MyEtherWallet (and probably Mycrypto.com) image below :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source for Interact with contract: https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/MyEtherWallet/blob/master/src/layouts/InterfaceLayout/containers/InteractWithContractContainer/InteractWithContractContainer.vue

Here's the source for Deploy contract: https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/MyEtherWallet/blob/master/src/layouts/InterfaceLayout/containers/DeployContractContainer/DeployContractContainer.vue

Comment: the links are dead. do you still have the code ?